# IE8 background-size polyfill on :before and :after pseudoelements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm using [louisremi's excellent polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) for CSS background-size in IE8, however it doesn't appear to take any effect on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Devtools in IE8 shows the `behavior` property as crossed out, seemingly because it is considered invalid. However, [IE docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) show that the behavior property may be applied to all elements.

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it is, unfortunately, a known limitation of the polyfill: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill/issues/46#issuecomment-43063075